# Finding the intersection between a triangle and a parabola in 3-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

The problem can be stated using the following vector equation

$$o_1+tw+t^2g=o_2+au+bv$$

where $o_1$ is a point on the curve (the starting point of the projectile), $w$ is a vector facing in the direction of the curve (the direction of launch), $g$ is a vector pointing down (gravity), $o_2$ is one of the triangles vertices and $u$ and $v$ are vectors from that vertex to the other two.

Solving the equation should give us $t$, $a$ and $b$.

Doing this on paper quickly got out of hand so I've plugged it into Mathematica to get the solution and it's huge so I'll only post the equation for one of the possible solutions for $t$.

$$\frac{(-u[3])v[2]w[1] + u[2]v[3]w[1] + u[3]v[1]w[2] -
      u[1]v[3]w[2] - u[2]v[1]w[3] + u[1]v[2]w[3] -
      \sqrt{-4((-g)u[3]v[1] + gu[1]v[3])(o[3]u[2]v[1] - 
          p[3]u[2]v[1] - o[2]u[3]v[1] + p[2]u[3]v[1] - o[3]u[1]v[2] +
          p[3]u[1]v[2] + o[1]u[3]v[2] - p[1]u[3]v[2] + o[2]u[1]v[3] -
          p[2]u[1]v[3] - o[1]u[2]v[3] + p[1]u[2]v[3]) +
        (u[3]v[2]w[1] - u[2]v[3]w[1] - u[3]v[1]w[2] + u[1]v[3]w[2] +
          u[2]v[1]w[3] - u[1]v[2]w[3])^2}}{2((-g)u[3]v[1] + gu[1]v[3])}$$

the problem here is that I have the added condition that the denominator must not be zero, but in case it is zero, I have no idea what to do. I don't know what the geometric interpretation is of that number being zero so I don't see how assuming it's zero simplifies my problem to something I can solve.

Now for the actual question, is there a different approach to solving this that produces a cleaner solution? Perhaps I can somehow get away with manipulating vectors without dropping down to their coordinates? Maybe there's an interesting way I can transform my data into something workable?

Comment: Without trying to decipher the horrible expression you ended up with, I’d guess that a zero denominator indicates that the triangle doesn’t intersect the plane of motion.

Comment: Instead of trying to come up with a single closed-form solution, I recommend doing this in stages. First, reduce it to a two-dimensional problem: the projectile moves in a plane defined by $w$ and $g$; the triangle, if it intersects this plane at all, does so in a line segment. Computing the 2-d intersection of a parabola and a line is relatively simple.

Comment: @amd the case with no solution is probably when the thing under the root is less than zero. The thing in the denominator is just some consequence of the algebraic manipulations I think. As for doing it in steps, I thought about that but I don't think it simplifies things too much.

Comment: @amd I'm actually sure about there being cases with solutions that have a zero in the denominator.

Comment: The line of intersection between the plane of motion and the plane of the triangle has at most two intersections with the parabola. It’s simple enough to test if either of them is actually in the triangle.

Comment: It looks like you switch from $g$ being a vector in the first paragraph to a scalar in your expression for the intersection. The denominator doesn’t makes sense with a vector $g$, but it does as the dot product of $(0,g,0)$ with $u\times v$. That also explains when the denominator is zero: when the triangle is parallel to the direction of gravity (or you have a degenerate triangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try choosing a convenient set of basis vectors. I'll rename things slightly, so that my basis consists of vectors $u$, $v$, $w:=u\times v$, my direction vector is $d$, gravity vector $g$, initial position vector $p$, and triangle vertex $q$.

Now, given this vector equation ...
$$p + t d + t^2 g = q + a u + b v \tag{1}$$
... we take the dot product of each side with $w$ to get ...
$$t^2 w\cdot g+ t w\cdot d + w\cdot (p-q) = 0 \tag{2}$$
... which we easily solve for $t$:
$$t = \frac{-w\cdot d \pm \sqrt{ (w\cdot d)^2 - 4(w\cdot (p-q))(w\cdot g)}}{2w\cdot g} \tag{3}$$

To simplify, let's take $p = 0$, and let's define ...
$$D = \angle wd \qquad Q := \angle wq \qquad G := \angle wg$$
... so that we can write ...
$$\begin{align}
t &= \frac{-|w||d|\cos D \pm \sqrt{ |w|^2|d|^2\cos^2D + 4|w|^2|q||g|\cos Q\cos G}}{2|w||g|\cos G} \\
&= \frac{-|d|\cos D \pm \sqrt{ |d|^2\cos^2D + 4|q||g|\cos Q\cos G}}{2|g|\cos G}
\end{align}\tag{4}$$
The geometric interpretation of a zero denominator here is clear: either the gravity vector has zero magnitude, or $G$ is a right angle (in which case, the pull of gravity is parallel to the plane of the triangle). In either case, the quadratic in $(2)$ is only linear in $t$ (provided $w\cdot d \neq 0$), which is easier to solve, anyway.

Comment: Perfect! Just the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Any idea why the equation becomes linear if the triangle is parallel with the direction of gravity? It seems it should still be quadratic.

Comment: Oh, because the gravity doesn't affect when the projectile reaches the target plane.

Comment: Thanks, nice presentation of that solution. However on a practical note (since my interest is the collision of a particle on a parabolic trajectory with the triangular faces of an object model), I believe that what you are referring to as the "gravity vector" g should actually be HALF the acceleration, because velocity over time is v = at, and distance over time is the integral of that: d = (at^2)/2

Comment: @CuriousKea: The vector $g$ can be whatever you want, or HALF of whatever you want. So far as the analysis is concerned, it's just an arbitrary vector pointing in the direction of "gravity", as in the original problem statement.